# Ti.Media.createSound not working in Android 6.0 when streaming file from server

Tags: android-mediaplayer, appcelerator, android-6.0-marshmallow, appcelerator-titanium

I am using appcelerator sdk 5.1.2 and trying to build for Android 6.0. Ti.Media.createSound not able to stream mp3 file hosted on server. I am trying to play an mp3 file which is hosted on server but nothing happens i.e file not play. Here is my simple code.

```
var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
   url : 'url to mp3 file on server',
   allowBackground : true
});
sound.play();
```

Nothing showed up in console. Same code working absolutely fine when build for Android 5.1.0 but not works for Android 6.0. Anyone knows what the problem is.

Comment: Can you try small sound file ?? like 3sec .

Comment: `Ti.Media.Sound` is not for streaming. Use `Ti.Media.AudioPlayer` instead.

Comment: Sure i would give it a try. But why Ti.Media.Sound is working for all Android API's except 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem in streaming of mp3 or audio files in titanium for marshmallow. I faced the same problem. You can either try to provide storage permission for your app or try to compile with the 5.4.0 SDK as they are saying that it is fixed in this SDK

[TIMOB-20140](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20140) [TIMOB-20234](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20234)

Hope this will help you.